# Pandas csv not reading Arabic characters

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nlp, arabic

I have a csv file with mixed columns of numbers and Arabic text. I am trying to open it using pandas csv reader. I tried using the following.

```
Text= pd.read_csv('text.csv', encoding ='utf-8-sig')
```

However, after reading the file, when I am looking at the columns, I am getting instead of Arabic text a bunch of exclamation marks for each row.
what could be the problem?

thanks

Comment: Please provide a text sample of `text.csv` to reproduce the issue, the output it produces, and the desired output.  See the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: I just realized that there was something wrong in the excel sheet. I don't know what happened, one moment it looked fine and then when I opened it today the Arabic text cells were only showing ???. Anyway I used a different excel sheet and now it is working fine. thanks.